# Node.JS Puppeteer: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. (Heroku Deployment)

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

I have a really simple test app that runs (nearly) without error locally, but on my Heroku deployment, things don't go as smooth. Here are the basics of the app.

Puppeteer options:

```
const puppetOptions = {
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: [
        "--incognito",
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--single-process",
        "--no-zygote"
    ],     
}
```

Website scrape function:

```
module.exports.checkWebsite = async (url, int) => {
    console.log(`Scraping site...`);
    // launch a browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(constants.puppetOptions);
    try {
        // open a new page
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // navigate to URL
        await page.goto(url);
        // Find a specific element on the page
        const element = await page.$('element.class');
        // If the element exists, log success, and clear the setInterval function
        // If not, log it and let the periodic scrape continue
        if (element) {
            console.log(`Element Available...`);
            clearInterval(int)
        } else {
            console.log(`Element Not Available...`);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Website Scrape Error!`, err);
    } finally {
        // Regardless of the outcome, shutdown the browser
        console.log('Closing browser...');
        await browser.close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Then the basic server running things:

```
let checkWebsiteRun;
let checkWebsite2Run;

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {

    console.log('Running server...');

    checkWebsiteRun = setInterval(() => {
        checkWebsite("https://google.com", checkWebsiteRun);
    }, 1000 * 60);

    checkWebsite2Run = setInterval(() => {
        checkWebsite("https://yahoo.com", checkWebsite2Run);
    }, 1000 * 60);

})
```

Now in reality, I have been trying to have about four of these interval scrapes happening on different sites simultaneously. Seems to be the more I add, the more likely I am to have this `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter` error pop up. And additionally the more likely I am to get `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded` errors on seemingly random instances of my scrapes. To make matters more confusing, the app seems to perform its worst on the first several attempts, getting timeout errors, and max listener errors, but then seems to level out and run somewhat smoothly after failing for a while.

I suppose my primary question is, is there some sort of cleanup I'm not performing in my application, or is there some major inefficiency I'm performing in bad practice? Maybe opening too many headless browsers? Maybe closing and reopening the browser instead of refreshing the page? Maybe having individual browsers for each site scrape?

Comment: You're launching new browsers faster than old ones are closing. I suggest not using setInterval for things like this.

Comment: @pguardiario thanks, do you have a suggestion for an alternative method? The close browser seems to run before each new interval. So is it that I using separate browsers for each individual scrape?

Comment: If you await the function in a loop, you'll know that it always finishes before it does another one.

Comment: @pguardiario I guess I didn't think of that. I sort of intended to run it on a set interval, but I may as well just run it in a natural for loop. It's been so long that I've used a for loop, it sort of didn't even occur to me as an option. I'll give that a shot tomorrow to see if it clears up the errors. Thanks dude.